# How to return only value of a field in mongodb using node js.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I queried my mongodb database with this method:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    user.find({}, {twitter: 0, _id: 0, __v:0,}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err; 

        console.log(result); 

        res.render('pages/index', {

            path: result


        });
    });

});
```

I got this result in return:

```
{ meme: { imgs: 'http://localhost/public/Images/okro.jpg' } }
{ meme: { imgs: 'http://localhost/public/Images/1518530337363-okro.jpg' } }
{ meme: { imgs: 'http://localhost/public/Images/1518530481130-meme.jpg' } }
```

But what I wanted it to return the actual value in the `imgs` field.

I want something like this.

```
 {'http://localhost/public/Images/okro.jpg'} 
{'http://localhost/public/Images/1518530337363-okro.jpg'} 
{ 'http://localhost/public/Images/1518530481130-meme.jpg' }
```

How is this possible in MongoDB using node js?

Comment: Use aggregation.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using? Is your expected output even valid JSON? Did you mean an ouput of an array with a single element e.g `['http://localhost/public/Images/okro.jpg']` because `{'http://localhost/public/Images/okro.jpg'}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Exactly that's what I wanted. @chridam. I'm connecting remotely to Mlab.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply parse the result.Updated Answer.

```
user.find({},{_id: 0,details:0,name:0 },function(err, docs){
  docs.forEach(function(u) {
        u=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(u))
        console.log(u.meme); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer is returning 'forEach' is not a function.

Comment: Sorry my bad updated the answer.If you think it is working as expected upvote it.

Comment: Hey @dev9, how do I present it to the frontend using ejs?  Thank you, your answer is working.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need duplicate values, you can use `distinct`

```
 db.collection.distinct('meme.imgs')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var condition1 = { $match: { 'twitter':  { $eq: 0 }  } };    
var condition2 = { $match: { '_id':  { $eq: 0 }  } };
var condition3 = { $match: { '_id':  { $eq: Schema('11111111111111111') }  } };
var condition4 = { $match: { '__v':  { $eq: 0 }  } };
var project = { "$project": { 
                        "imgs": '$meme.imgs'                            
                    }
        };
user.find({}, {condition1,condition2,condition3,condition4,project}, function (err, result) {

})
```